# Was unable to sort a list of objects in flutter

Tags: firebase, sorting, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was working on a project where I need to sort a list that has objects in it, but it's giving an error.

```
The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used.
```

Here my code:-

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        messageList = datasnapshot.documents
            .map(
              (v) => Message(
                  message: v.data['msg'],
                  sender: v.data['sender'],
                  imgUrl: v.data['imgUrl'],
                  id: v.data['id']),
            )
            .toList().sort((m, m2) => int.parse(m.id).compareTo(int.parse(m2.id)));


      });
    });
  }
```

Its raising error at sort method :-

```
.toList().sort((m, m2) => int.parse(m.id).compareTo(int.parse(m2.id)));
```

What should I do to fix it, or is there any other way to sort a list of objects.

**One more extra question. Documents in my firestore collection are not being added chronologically-sorted. so, I have to do that manually. do anyone knows why they are not being chronologically-sorted as default?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I am not that good at English. I will improve it. Thanks

Comment: Documents are not added chronologically-sorted because this is done at the query level. Indexing is already applied automatically when new documents are added, which is how the query can sort the documents quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sort method doesn't return a list, it is a void function. You should do it like this:

```
messageList = datasnapshot.documents
        .map(
          (v) => Message(
              message: v.data['msg'],
              sender: v.data['sender'],
              imgUrl: v.data['imgUrl'],
              id: v.data['id']),
        )
        .toList()

messageList.sort((m, m2) => int.parse(m.id).compareTo(int.parse(m2.id)));
```

Comment: yeah, that totally makes sense. Thanks for your answer. I was struggling for it from couple of hours. Really appreciated. Thanks ones again.

Comment: I can't find the difference between this answer and the code in the question. Did you edit it to match this answer?